# Query for joining all info from three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join

I need to Join 3 tables in SQL Server. Those 3 tables have basically this schema:

```
   Users                Items                     UsersItems
+--------+    +--------+-------------+    +--------+--------+-------+
| UserID |    | ItemID | Description |    | UserID | ItemId | Value |
+--------+    +--------+-------------+    +--------+--------+-------+
|   1    |    |   1    |    desc1    |    |   1    |    1   |   1   |
|   2    |    |   2    |    desc2    |    |   1    |    2   |   2   |
|  ...   |    |  ...   |    desc3    |    |   2    |    2   |   1   |
|   n    |    |   n    |    desc4    |    |   n    |    1   |   1   |
+--------+    +--------+-------------+    +--------+--------+-------+
```

As you can see both Users and Items can grow indefinitely and UsersItems is used to express the relation between those two, also including a Value column.

I need a query to retrieve all users, and for **each user** I need all the items with it's corresponding Value.

If the relation doesn't exist in `UsersItems` then Null (or a default value) should be returned for that row's `Value` column.

The expected query result should be:

```
             ResultSet
    +--------+--------+-------+
    | UserID | ItemID | Value |
    +--------+--------+-------+
    |   1    |   1    |   1   |
    |   1    |   2    |   2   |
    |   1    |   n    |  NULL |
    |   2    |   1    |  NULL |
    |   2    |   2    |   1   |
    |   2    |   n    |  NULL |
    |   n    |   1    |   1   |
    |   n    |   n    |  NULL |
    +--------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Read about LEFT JOIN and try something.

Comment: Actually, read about CROSS JOIN too.

Comment: Are you asking us to do your homework?

Comment: @Neil I have an idea of the join's Venn Diagram, I just dunno how to transform that into a query, basically because I understand that what I need is (U and UI) and (I and UI) but since those two would not return compatible results sets then I can't call `Union` on them.

Comment: @PMV I would've used the `Homework` tag. I'm asking because I need that query for an app and dunno how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, since there are several answers that I think aren't correct, I'll post what I think the answer is:

```
SELECT Users.UserID,
       Items.Description,
       UsersItems.Value
FROM
       Users
CROSS JOIN
       Items
LEFT JOIN
       UsersItems
ON
       Users.UserID = UsersItems.UserID
AND
       Items.ItemID = UsersItems.ItemID
```

I'm inferring from your comment about nulls that you want to see all Items againsts all Users, with the Value from the UsersItems table where it exists.

Comment: That was the query I had when I gave up, I was just lacking the `AND` statement at the end thus I was getting values in the `Value` column that weren't real. Than you!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
     Users.UserID,
     Items.Description,
     Items.Value

FROM Users LEFT OUTER JOIN UsersItems
          ON Users.UserID = UsersItems.UserID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Items
          ON UserItems.ItemID = Items.ItemID
```

Comment: That's not going to work, because if there's no row in UsersItems, you can't join to Items.

Comment: He said null is fine if there is no relation, thats why its an outer join

Comment: @paulbailey the outer join selects NULL if there is no connection, and selects the info if there is a connection between the tables. It's exactly what you want. Maess is correct.

Comment: I think it's just about how I read the question then, since he only specifies null for the value column.

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this:

```
SELECT Users.UserID, Items.Description, Items.Value
FROM Users
LEFT OUTER JOIN UsersItems ON Users.UserID = UsersItems.UserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Items ON UserItems.ItemID = Items.ItemID
```

---

For more info on left outer join read the following:

> The result of a left outer join (or simply left join) for table A and
>   B always contains all records of the "left" table (A), even if the
>   join-condition does not find any matching record in the "right" table
>   (B). This means that if the ON clause matches 0 (zero) records in B,
>   the join will still return a row in the result—but with NULL in each
>   column from B. This means that a left outer join returns all the
>   values from the left table, plus matched values from the right table
>   (or NULL in case of no matching join predicate). If the right table
>   returns one row and the left table returns more than one matching row
>   for it, the values in the right table will be repeated for each
>   distinct row on the left table. From Oracle 9i onwards the LEFT OUTER
>   JOIN statement can be used as well as (+).